# Have GitPython stage itself

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am new to GitPython and I am trying to have a python program stage itself to a new git repository (my-new-repo).

My main.py is as follows:

```
import git


repo = git.Repo.init('my-new-repo')

# List all branches
for branch in repo.branches:
    print(branch)

# Provide a list of the files to stage
repo.index.add(['main.py'])
# Provide a commit message
repo.index.commit('Initial commit')
```

File tree:

```
├── main.py
├── my-new-repo (directory)
    ├── .git
```

But when I run it, it returns this error:

```
No such file or directory: 'main.py' 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aaron/Downloads/GitPython/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    repo.index.add(['main.py'])
  File "/home/aaron/Downloads/GitPython/git/index/base.py", line 815, in add
    entries_added.extend(self._entries_for_paths(paths, path_rewriter, fprogress, entries))
  File "/home/aaron/Downloads/GitPython/git/util.py", line 144, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aaron/Downloads/GitPython/git/index/util.py", line 109, in set_git_working_dir
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aaron/Downloads/GitPython/git/index/base.py", line 694, in _entries_for_paths
    entries_added.append(self._store_path(filepath, fprogress))
  File "/home/aaron/Downloads/GitPython/git/index/base.py", line 639, in _store_path
    st = os.lstat(filepath)  # handles non-symlinks as well
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'main.py'
        Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: As `repo` refers to the initialized repository `my-new-repo`, `repo.index.add(['main.py'])` requires `main.py` to be inside `my-new-repo`.

Answer (score 1):

GitPython's `repo.index.add` function stages files from the directory of the repo. `git.Repo.init('my-new-repo')` creates a new repo in the (possibly new) directory my-new-repo. If main.py is not in the repo directory, then GitPython won't be able to see it.

To fix this, you can copy main.py into the repo's directory. Like this:

```
import git
import shutil


repo = git.Repo.init('my-new-repo')

# List all branches
for branch in repo.branches:
    print(branch)

# copy main.py into my-new-repo
shutil.copy('main.py', 'my-new-repo/main.py')

# Provide a list of the files to stage
repo.index.add(['main.py'])
# Provide a commit message
repo.index.commit('Initial commit')
```